# Make file open in current WPF application

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have a WPF application that I've associated with a custom file type.

The steps were:
1. Open Project Properties->Publish->Options->File Associations
2. Filled in Extension = .tr2, Description = TR2 file, ProgID = TR2File.tr2, Icon = W32.ico
3. Opened a blank text file, renamed it to test.tr2, double click it and the program starts up.
4. Created a second file, named test2.tr2, double click it and a second instance of my program starts up.

Now, I still haven't figured out how to actually open/read the files yet, but first I would really like to make it so that if the program is already running, then it just opens in the current app, and doesn't try to open a new instance of the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have your program create a [named pipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx).  When a second instance executes, before it does anything else, have it check for the existence of this named pipe.  If it exists, open it and use it to send the filename being opened in the second instance, and then terminate.  If it doesn't exist you don't have an existing instance, so you can open.

Comment: This worked surprisingly well... How do you close all pipe threads once you want to exit the program?

Comment: You can make any threads exit themselves cleanly simply by breaking out of the loop they're executing -- when the thread's function exits, the thread terminates. Typically you will want a class field like shouldExit and use lock { } around its access. If you want to be lazy, though, you can call System.Environment.Exit to terminate everything instantly.

Comment: So for future reference, here is the solution that I came up with: The thread wasn't going in a loop, it was paused at the `pipeServer.WaitForConnection()` command, meaning that it wouldn't respond to any shouldExit orders. So I decided to give it a connection and use that to break the loop and abort the thread. So in the programs closing event, I added `PipeClient.PipeClientMain({"", "ThreadCancel"})` and put an if statement in the pipe server that would close the pipe and abort the thread.